# "Quoting" argument variable in LESS mixin

Tags: css, less, lessphp

I have the following array of color definitions:

```
@colors: ~"black" #000, ~"white" #fff, ~"blue" #008FD6, ~"bluehover" #44A1E0, ~"grayborder" #DBDBDB;
```

And I use the following function to use those colors within CSS declarations.

```
.colorkey(@key) {
    .-(length(@colors));
    .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {.-((@i - 1))}
    .-(@i) when (@key = extract(extract(@colors, @i), 1)) {
        @colorkey: extract(extract(@colors, @i), 2);
    }

    .--() {@colorkey: #000} .--;
}
```

Usage:

```
.my-div {
     .colorkey(~"black");
     color: @colorkey
}
```

However I'd prefer to use the mixin like so:

```
.colorkey(black);
```

Without the quotes and tilde. Is it possible to modify the colorkey mixin to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your `@colors` can be defined without putting the color names in `~"..."`, you just need to make a minor change:

```
@colors: black #000, white #fff, blue #008FD6, bluehover #44A1E0, grayborder #DBDBDB;

.colorkey(@key:black) {
    .-(length(@colors));
    .-(@i) when (@key = extract(extract(@colors, @i), 1)) {
        @colorkey: extract(extract(@colors, @i), 2);
    }
    .-(@i) when (@i > 0) {.-(@i - 1)}
}

.my-div {
     .colorkey(bluehover);
     color: @colorkey
}
```

Note that I

- removed the extra set of parentheses in your `.-(@i) when (@i > 0)`
- moved that recursive call to the end of `.colorkey`, and
- dropped your `.--() {@colorkey: #000} .--;` and in its place used `.colorkey(@key:black) {`. (My guess is that was supposed to make `.colorkey; color: @colorkey` evaluate to `color: #000` but actually it wasn't doing anything :) In the code you provided, to define that default you'd need instead to do `.colorkey(@key: ~"black") {` )